# pass tkinter openfilename to a instance variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Checked:

[python pass variable tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589642/python-pass-variable-tkinter)

[Tkinter - How to pass instance variable to another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858446/tkinter-how-to-pass-instance-variable-to-another-class)

and other web resources but didn't find a solution.

I have a Tkinter button to open file:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from myClass import my_function 

class select_file:
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.filename = ""

    tk.Button(self.root, text="Browse", command=self.open).pack()
    self.root.mainloop()

def open(self):
    filetypes = (('LOG files', '*.LOG'), ('All files', '*.*'))
    self.filename = fd.askopenfilename(title='open LOG file', filetypes=filetypes)

    
    self.root.destroy()
    print(self.filename)
    return self.filename
```

and that's work fine since I can get the file path in right way.

Output:

C:/Users/xxxx/xxxxx/Dataset/SC180918.LOG

My question is how I can pass the selected filename as instance variable to other function within same project but in another file (myClass.py):

```
class my_function:
log_frame = pd.DataFrame()


def __init__(self, file):
    self.file = file

 def create_df(self):
    myClass.log_frame = pd.read_table(self.file, sep=';', index_col='TimeStamp', parse_dates=True)
    return myClass.log_frame
```

My task is to pass the file to create_df.
I tried several code I will not post to avoid confusion and not working code.

Comment: What does "_I tried several code I will not post to avoid confusion and not working code._" mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the file is important, I generated two python files as below:

myClass.py:

```
class my_function:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
    def create_df(self):
        print("filename in my_function is ",self.file)
```

testMe.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from myClass import my_function 

class select_file:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.filename = ""
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Browse", command=self.open).pack()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def open(self):
        filetypes = (('LOG files', '*.LOG'), ('All files', '*.*'))
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename(title='open LOG file', filetypes=filetypes)    
        self.root.destroy()
        print("filename in select_file is ",self.filename)
        return self.filename

sfClass = select_file() # select filename by Browse
filename = sfClass.filename # get filename from the class
mfClass = my_function(filename) # pass it to the class
mfClass.create_df()
```

here is the output if I select testMe.py file:

```
filename in select_file is  C:/Users/XXX/XXX/SOquestions/testMe.py
filename in my_function is  C:/Users/XXX/XXX/SOquestions/testMe.py
```

as a result, filename has been successfully passed to the `my_function`.

I tested as below as well:

```
print(mfClass.file)
```

it prints: `C:/Users/XXX/XXX/SOquestions/testMe.py`

Answer (score 1):

I would do as following;

```
sfClass = select_file() # select filename by Browse
filename = sfClass.filename # get filename from the class
mfClass = my_function(filename) # pass it to the class
```

Comment: Following your solution the following error is raised:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file'

Comment: can you share the error? Because it worked for me.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file'


the file has to be passed to function that creates pandas dataframe:def
    create_df(self):
       myClass.log_frame = pd.read_table(self.file, sep=';', index_col='TimeStamp',parse_dates=True, skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11])